# Seeding mongodb using node error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, npm

nodejs, express, mongoose project
trying to seed the database
mongo acivated but I get the error when I run the following:

$ node product-seeder.js

(node:2810) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid schema, expected `mongodb` or `mongodb+srv`

```
at module.exports (/Users/MXD/Sites/adx/hosted/ShoppingCartwithNodeJSExpressAuthentic/shopping-cart/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:15:21)
at Promise (/Users/MXD/Sites/adx/hosted/ShoppingCartwithNodeJSExpressAuthentic/shopping-cart/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:330:5)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/MXD/Sites/adx/hosted/ShoppingCartwithNodeJSExpressAuthentic/shopping-cart/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:329:17)
at Mongoose.connect (/Users/MXD/Sites/adx/hosted/ShoppingCartwithNodeJSExpressAuthentic/shopping-cart/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:206:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/MXD/Sites/adx/hosted/ShoppingCartwithNodeJSExpressAuthentic/shopping-cart/seed/product-seeder.js:5:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:193:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:617:3
```

product-seeder.js

```
var Product = require('../models/product');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/shopping');

var products = [
    new Product({
      imagePath: 'images/black_tee_flagship_p_symbol_right_340x380.png',
      title: 'Black Tee White P',
      description: 'P on chest [white], symbols on sleeve',
      price: 28
    }),
    new Product({
      imagePath: 'images/white_tee_purple_eye_pocket_340x380.png',
      title: 'White Tee Purple Eye',
      description: 'Embroidered Purple Eye',
      price: 28
    }),
    new Product({
      imagePath: 'images/black_tee_gold_dual_p_center_340x380.png',
      title: 'Black Tee Gold 2Ps',
      description: 'Black Tee 2Ps on Chest [gold]',
      price: 28
    }),
    new Product({
      imagePath: 'images/white_tee_p_symbol_popular_text_340x380.png',
      title: 'White Tee Purple P',
      description: 'P Logo + POPULAR underneath',
      price: 28
    }),
    new Product({
      imagePath: 'images/black_tee_blue_dual_p_symbol_right_dual_p_left_340x380.png',
      title: 'Black Tee Blue 2Ps',
      description: '2Ps on chest, symbols + 2ps on sleeve',
      price: 28
    }),
    new Product({
      imagePath: 'images/white_tee_popular_blackboxed_center_340x380.png',
      title: 'White Tee POPULAR',
      description: 'POPULAR on chest [white on black]',
      price: 28
    })
];

var done = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    products[i].save(function(err, result) {
        done++;
        if (done === products.length) {
            exit();
        }
    });
}

function exit() {
    mongoose.disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection string is in need of updating: It is missing a URL schema.

Your connection string needs to be this:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/shopping');
```

Since `27017` is the default port for MongoDB, you can leave it out.

[More infos](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)